# Get parent entity ID when comparing list of child entities

Tags: java, javers

Javers v5.6.3

I have a parent entity which contains a list of child entities. When I diff 2 lists of parents and a change is found in a child, I need to know which parent contains the changed child.

**My entities:**

```
@TypeName("Parent")
class Parent {
    @Id
    private String parentId;
    private Set<Child> children;
}

@TypeName("Child")
class Child {
    @Id
    private String childId;
    private String someProp;
}
```

**What I'm trying to diff:**

Switching to Groovy for brevity:

```
def list1 = [
      new Parent(parentId:'p1', children: [new Child(childId: 'c1')]),
      new Parent(parentId:'p2', children: [new Child(childId: 'c2', someProp: 'fig')])
]
def list2 = [
      new Parent(parentId:'p1', children: [new Child(childId: 'c1', someProp: 'apple')]),
      new Parent(parentId:'p2', children: [new Child(childId: 'c2', someProp: 'fig')])
]
```

**How I'm diffing:**

```
Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers()
                  .withListCompareAlgorithm(ListCompareAlgorithm.AS_SET)
                  .build();

Diff diff = javers.compareCollections(list1, list2);
System.out.println(diff);
```

**The ouput:**

```
Diff:
* changes on Child/c1 :
  - 'someProp' value changed from '' to 'apple'
```

**My question:**

How do I discover which parent contains Child/c1?

This is similar to the [shouldDetectSalaryChange() example](https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/javers-core/src/test/java/org/javers/core/examples/EmployeeHierarchiesDiffExample.java#L72) except I have a collection of bosses.  Using that example, given a list of bosses with different subordinates, how would one find out the boss of `Great Developer`?

Do I need to create a custom `Parent` comparator or is there a way to find out from the built-in comparators?

Comment: good question. I will try to give an answer tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having this mapping, you can't discover which Parent contains Child/c1 because Child class is mapped as Entity. So Javers doesn't know about this parent-child relationship.

You can change the mapping of Child class to ValueObject to make this relation explicit:

```java
    @TypeName("Parent")
    class Parent {
        @Id
        private String parentId
        private Set<Child> children
    }

    @TypeName("Child")
    class Child {
        private String childId
        private String someProp
    }
```

and then:

```java
        Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers()
                .withListCompareAlgorithm(ListCompareAlgorithm.AS_SET)
                .wi
                .build()

        Diff diff = javers.compareCollections(list1, list2, Parent)

        println(diff)
```

prints:

```
Diff:
* new object: Parent/p1#children/5f6ade8312fb0c5d60f756841e23af65
* object removed: Parent/p1#children/9de1d946eab394f971263c33e297f86d
* changes on Parent/p1 :
  - 'children' collection changes :
    . 'Parent/p1#children/9de1d946eab394f971263c33e297f86d' removed
    . 'Parent/p1#children/5f6ade8312fb0c5d60f756841e23af65' added
```

Comment: I tried that and it is not satisfactory because, instead of a property change the change is an add/remove.  Add/remove is not what happened from the perspective of "real life".  Using the "shouldDetectSalaryChange" example, the salary change would be reported as an employee gain and an employee loss.  The solution I came up with is to diff the lists in 2 steps. The first step is to determine the changes to the lists of Parents (i.e. Parents added/removed). The second step is to diff each pair of Parent entities (instead of the lists of parents).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to thank you for your answer.  I appreciate the quick and thorough response! I realize that I may be using Javers for something it's not intended to be used for. I'm diffing the output of existing code and replacement code to ensure the replacement code gives the same results. The output contains a list objects composed of entities which contain other entities. We're not using Javers when we persist the entities, though that's my plan now that I've used Javers.

Comment: Well, if you want to keep Child as Entity, which is fine, why not simply add in your model the back-ref from Child to Parent? Another solution could rely on getting this relation from ObjectGraph (https://github.com/javers/javers/blob/master/javers-core/src/main/java/org/javers/core/graph/ObjectGraph.java) which is internally used by Javers, but exposing this structure to end-user would require changes in javers-core.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Some child entities can be a child of multiple parents (i.e. many to many).  As I said I think this may be an unusual use case; that it hasn't come up before seems to confirm that.  My solution is simple and straightforward (at least to me). Javers meets all our normal persistence-related needs and I'm looking forward to using it to replace a bunch of custom diff code that isn't as good as what Javers provides. Thanks again!

Comment: Fine, hope that JaversRepository will do the job for you.